# Background image hover transition not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

CSS Transition is not working in chrome on image hover, please check the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/d6qf0dtr/) example

**HTML**

```
<div class="screenThum">
  <a href="#" class="portfolio" style="background-image:url(http://toffeeglobal.com/images/mockup1.png);"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.screenThum .portfolio{
  width:350px; 
  display:block; 
  height:100%; 
  background-size:100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:250px; 
  position:relative; 
  opacity:0.4; 
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 }

 .screenThum .portfolio:hover{
   opacity:0.9; 
   background-size:120%;
 }
```

I have tried with previous SO answers but didn't worked with my code, not sure whats wrong?

thanks

Comment: you mean zooming effect?

Comment: What is not working ? On my side the image is zoomed on hover ?

Comment: Yes, the zooming effect on hover

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet please check in chrome

Comment: Smoothness on hover is not as compared to Firefox.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qyh6nbwt/1/ Check this fiddle, using a wrapper and transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with it then you can use `transform:scale`
to get same effect. **Edited**: taking the reference of **@Alexandre Beaudet**

```css
.screenThum{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
}
.screenThum .portfolio{
  width:350px; 
  display:block; 
  height:100%; 
  background-size:100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:250px; 
  position:relative; 
  opacity:0.4; 
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;}

.screenThum .portfolio:hover{
    opacity:0.9; 
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2,1.2);   
    }
```

```html
<div class="screenThum"><a href="#" class="portfolio" style="background-image:url(http://toffeeglobal.com/images/mockup1.png);"></a></div>
```

Comment: You can also use a wrapping div around the image, so the borders are hidden when scaling it (which give a zoom effect, not a scaling up effect)

Comment: @Sagar thanks for your answer, but just wondering why the CSS which I originally coded isnt smooth in chrome..

Comment: @SanjeevK https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties Apparently, if I'm not making a mistake, background-image / size isn't an animatable property, so it would make sense that some browser can't animate them !

Comment: @SanjeevK Also think about giving the "answer token" to Sagar, his way is the best and cleanest you'll find I think !

Answer (score 1):

Try to set screenThump width & overflow: hidden. Then use the transform: scale(x) property. This way you will get the zoom effect and the image will not get out of the container width.

```
.screenThum {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 350px;
}
.screenThum .portfolio{
  width:350px; 
  display:block; 
  height:100%; 
  background-size:100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  height:250px; 
  position:relative; 
  opacity:0.4; 
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
   transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
 }

 .screenThum .portfolio:hover{
   opacity:0.9; 
   transform: scale(3);
 }
```